# How to move Flex Mobile ActionBar down just a little bit?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5, flex-mobile

I'm trying to simply move the actionBar down 75 pixels so I can squeeze an adMob ad in there.

I tried:

```
navigator.actionBar.y=75;
```

But, i'm not seeing anything different visually, it's not moving, it's giving me no errors, but if i do `trace(navigator.actionBar.y);` it claims it's at 75....even though it's clearly not on the screen.

Does anyone have any ideas? Also, this would only be for ONE view, I can't use a solution that would move the action bar down throughout the entire application. I just need it moved down in THIS particular view.

Thanks!

EDIT:
@Brian,
Thanks for the suggestion, almost done this whole mess. I'm trying to make a function inside the skin to add the space for the adMob ad. But, I don't think im referencing the function correctly, because when i do it im not getting any errors, and nothing is happening.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" >
    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("spark.components.ViewNavigator")]
    </fx:Metadata>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            public function adMobVisible(trueOrFalse:Boolean):void
            {
                if(trueOrFalse)
            {
                main_group.top=70;
            }
            else
            {
                main_group.top=0;
            }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- states -->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="landscapeAndOverlay" />
        <s:State name="portraitAndOverlay" />
        <s:State name="landscape" />
        <s:State name="portrait" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <!-- <s:State name="admob" /> -->
    </s:states>

    <s:VGroup id="main_group" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:ActionBar id="actionBar" width="100%" />
        <s:Group id="contentGroup" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Skin>
```

I did:

```
import skins.AdMobHolderSkin;

protected var ad:AdMobHolderSkin = new AdMobHolderSkin();
```

up top... then I just tried to do a simple thing like:

```
ad.adMobVisible(true);
```

But nothing happens. Any ideas? Thanks for helping with this.

Comment: I think the action bar is skinnable, you should look into that and manage it with states (so that in this specific view it's not in "normal" stage but in, say "adMob" state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the code for `ViewNavigatorSkin`, you will find that it lays out its two items (`ActionBar` and `Group`) using simple math.  In other words, it is not using a layout container in which setting `top` or `y` will have any effect.

Instead, you need to skin the `ViewNavigator`.  First, define the skin (notice how I set the `top="75"` in the `VGroup` :

**VNSkin.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("spark.components.ViewNavigator")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <!-- states -->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="landscapeAndOverlay" />
        <s:State name="portraitAndOverlay" />
        <s:State name="landscape" />
        <s:State name="portrait" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="moved" />
    </s:states>

    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" top="0" top.moved="75">
        <s:ActionBar id="actionBar" width="100%" />
        <s:Group id="contentGroup" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Skin>
```

Then, inside of my main application, I will skin the ViewNavigator to use this skin:

**MyApp.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" firstView="views.ActionbarMoveHomeView" applicationDPI="160" >  
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        s|ViewNavigator {
            skinClass: ClassReference("VNSkin")
        }   
    </fx:Style>
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

Finally, in my view, I need to set the state and put it back when the view is activated and deactivated:

**MyView.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:viewActivate>
        navigator.skin.currentState = "moved";
    </s:viewActivate>

    <s:viewDeactivate>
        navigator.skin.currentState = "normal";
    </s:viewDeactivate>

    <s:Label text="test" click="navigator.pushView(SecondPage)" />
</s:View>
```

Note that this technique adds some overhead because your `ViewNavigator` skin is now MXML instead of pure ActionScript.  You might consider creating a skin in pure ActionScript based off the `ViewNavigatorSkin` source code such that you can place it with your offset... but if you aren't noticing a huge performance hit from the MXML skin, I wouldn't worry about it.

**EDIT**
I noticed after I wrote my answer that you only want it for one view.  I have made a modification to add a state to the `VNSkin` class and then switch the states in the view code (`viewActivate` and `viewDeactivate`.  For the record, this all feels like a hack.  I'd consider some sort of notification mechanism so that you can communicate to the skin in order to change in a way other than this... but I have at least put you on a path to doing this with one technique.  I'd love to see someone come here and suggest something better.  Until then, you have something that works :P

Comment: Interesting idea to get this to work. I've got it setup and working. But how might you propose fixing the issue that comes up when someone turns the phone into landscape? I could add the padding to the landscape state...But then i'll be stuck with that in any view where someone puts the phone in landscape (rather than in just in one view where i want to have the ad)

Comment: Instead of using states, you could add a public function that sets the value imperatively and maintain all the existing states.  But, really that is only if you want to do something different for the different layouts.  If you are good with just a stack panel in both cases, you'd be fine.

Comment: Hey Brian, I made an edit up top since i tried the method of making a function, mind taking a quick look when you get a chance? Thanks!

Comment: See how I am setting `navigator.skin.currentState` in the view?  Well, `navigator.skin` will be of type `AdMobHolderSkin` if you set up the style properly.  That means you can do this: `navigator.skin. adMobVisible(true)` in place of what I had for the `currentState`.  Just to be save, wrap it in a condition to make sure you don't crash: `if("adMobVisible" in navigator.skin)`.  Duck typing FTW! :)

Comment: That was actually what i tried at first. But `navigator.skin.adMobVisible(true)` doesn't work. When i type `navigator.skin.` `adMobVisible(true)` doesn't come up in the code hinting.

Comment: It won't come up in code hinting.  You are calling it dynamically.  But it certainly should work.

Comment: If you want code hinting, you can always cast: `if(navigator.skin is AdMobHolderSkin) { (navigator.skin as AdMobHolderSkin).adMobVisible(true); }`

Comment: Hmm i'm still pretty new to programming so you lost me at the end of that one. But it works! So, thanks!

Comment: Well, `navigator.skin` is of type `UIComponent`.  The default type is `NavigatorSkin` which derives from `UIComponent` but the only code hinting you will get is for the properties and methods on `UIComponent`.  The IDE cannot know that you have set the skin to `AdMobHolderSkin` at runtime, so you never get code hinting.  If you cast it (coerce the value to the type you know it is), then the IDE can know the type and give you code hinting.  BUT, at runtime, if the value somehow is not of `AdMobHolderSkin`, you will throw an exception.  So you put a guard around it, making sure it is the type.

Comment: My earlier comment about calling it dynamically, meant that you can cast it in the opposite direction as well (navigator.skin as Object) and use "Duck Typing"  This is where you ask if it can do something at runtime... `if( "adMobVisible" in navigator.skin )`.  If it can, you can call it dynamically: `(navigator.skin as Object).adMobVisible(true)` but you won't get code hinting because the IDE doesn't know your type.  That is where casting it as the type you know it to be comes in.  Hope that helps :)